# Openbravo url query building with Inner Join, Right Join

Tags: hql, openbravo

I want to query openbravo to filter clients with their phone number. I have two tables BusinessPartner and BusinessPartnerLocation. BusinessPartnerLocation has phone field and businessPartner field that is the id of BusinessPartner object.
I tried like this http://server.opentix.es:3013/openbravo/org.openbravo.service.json.jsonrest/BusinessPartner?_where=e%20IN%20(%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20bp%20FROM%20BusinessPartner%20RIGHT%20JOIN%20BusinessPartnerLocation%20ON%20BusinessPartner.id=BusinessPartnerLocation.businessPartner%20WHERE%20BusinessPartnerLocation.phone='5555555')

without %20 s or without e In ()  still it didn't work. How can I build query for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
you should use below code that help to get both location geographical and businesspartner location without write hql.   

    bPartner = OBDao.getOBObjectListFromString(BusinessPartner.class,
            strcBpartnerId);

      List<Location> ls = bPartner.getBusinessPartnerLocationList();

                    if (!ls.isEmpty()) {
                     org.openbravo.model.common.businesspartner.Location Location lcbpartner = ls.get(0);
                   org.openbravo.model.common.geography.Location   lcgeo = lcbpartner.getLocationAddress();
                     org.openbravo.model.common.businesspartner.Location  lcbp = lcbpartner;
                    }
```